# Can we integrate $\int_a^b t^i f(t) \, dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

If we are given reals $a$ and $b$, and we have a function of $t$, $f(t)$, we can analyze the integral:

$$\int_a^b t^i f(t) \, dt$$

...where $i$ is the imaginary number.  I'm wondering if we can somehow solve this integral in terms of the integral of $f(t)$.  For instance, could we get something like:

$$\text{stuff} + \int_c^d f(t) \, dt $$

*Please note that the above function is just an example.*  I'm really wondering if there is some way to essentially eliminate the $t^i$ from the integral, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not that simple.  Even a factor of $t$ can't be eliminated so easily.
Thus $\int \dfrac{dt}{1+\exp(t)}$ is elementary, but $\int \dfrac{t\; dt}{1+\exp(t)}$ is not.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that there might be a way using integration by parts, especially with the function you give above.  If we allow substitution so that the function can be modified, does that significantly change our chances with $t^i$?

Comment: You can of course do integration by parts:
$$ \int t^i f(t)\; dt = \dfrac{t^{1+i} f(t)}{1+i} - \int \dfrac{t^{i+1}}{i+1} f'(t)\; dt $$